# Make a new pointer in a loop C

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to create a new pointer every iteration. Each pointing to its own memory location, holding the value of i at the time it is assigned. My approach is below but when I print the address of id, it is the same for each iteration.

**code**

```c
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    int id = i;
    printf("i[%p], ",&i);
    printf("id[%p]\n",&id);
}
```

**output**

```
i[565782000], id[565782004]
i[565782000], id[565782004]
i[565782000], id[565782004]
```

Comment: you should declare id outside the for loop. but either way the address of both will always be the same as where it is initially located on the stack

Comment: Shouldn't you print something like `d->id` and shouldn't `d` be an array of pointers?

Comment: What about your result is unexpected? You're printing the addresses of your loop counter and an integer variable local to the loop block...

Comment: Try something like `printf("%p\n", (void *)d);`.

Comment: I removed your C++ tag since your title says you are asking about C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` and `id` are both local variables with automatic storage (commonly referred to as *on the stack*). No *new* instances are *created* upon each iteration of the loop, the same space is reused and a new value is stored in `id`, hence the same addresses printed by `printf`.

Note that the value of `id` is not guaranteed to be preserved across iterations since it goes out of scope at the end of the block forming the body of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want each variable to have its own address and be rradable outside the loop, there are two things you can do.  First, and most sensibly, create an array of n elements and set `xs[i]` inside the loop.  Second, use `malloc()` and `free()`.

By the way, print pointers with `%p`, not `%d`.  A pointer is not necessarily the same size as an int.